# Doctrine middleware do not make flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, flush, symfony-messenger

My config/messanger.yaml looks like:

```yaml
framework:
    messenger:
        default_bus: command.bus
        buses:
            command.bus:
                middleware: 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Messenger\DoctrineTransactionMiddleware'
            query.bus: ~
```

And the command handler for command `UpdateUser` looks like this:

```php
final class UpdateUserHandler implements CommandHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Users
     */
    private Users $users;

    public function __construct(Users $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    public function __invoke(UpdateUser $command)
    {
        $user = $command->getUser();
        $user->setName($command->getName());
    }
```

And now I am dispatching this command from the controller:

```php
final class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private CommandBus $commandBus;

    public function __construct(CommandBus $commandBus)
    {
        $this->commandBus = $commandBus;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request, User $user): Response
    {
        $this->commandBus->dispatch(new UpdateUser($user, $name));

        return $this->render('user.html.twig', []);
    }
}
```

Could you tell me why automatic flush on middleware `DoctrineTransactionMiddleware` does not work?
What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
final class UpdateUserHandler implements CommandHandlerInterface
{
/**
 * @var Users
 */
private Users $users;

private EntityManagerInterface $em;


public function __construct(Users $users, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->users = $users;
    $this->em = $em;
}

public function __invoke(UpdateUser $command)
{
    $user = $command->getUser();
    $user->setName($command->getName());
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

}

Better call flush method explicitly.

Comment: It's better to do it in middlewarw